# Can I catch keyboard events in Flex, without forcing users to click on the stage?

Tags: apache-flex, events, keyboard

Greetings, 
Looking at the examples I've found as a result of Google searches, I can see that the common method suggested for handling global keyboard events in Flex, is to attach a listener in the application complete event of a Flex application. 
However, no matter what I try, I have not been able to catch events without clicking on a point on the page, which is hosting my Flex application. 
Moreoever, if I use a Flex component in a web application, where there is also html and Javascript, I'd still like to be able to grap global keyboard events, even if the embedded flex component (in flash player) does not have focus.

So is there a reliable method for connecting flex applications and components (when they're embedded in a web page) to keyboard events?

Best Regards
Seref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the javascript bridge.  You would need to set up listeners in javascript that pass data to your Flex application.

As for directly capturing them, the browser will only send events to the Flash plugin if the plugin has focus, so no, you cannot capture them directly in your Flex application.

Comment: Thanks Alan. Strange, all the documentation and snippets around gives you this impression, but what you're saying makes sense indeed. It appears some javascript hacking is on the way.